# Excel data to table on Dashing Dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, dashing, roo

I have been trying to convert a Dashing widget called [spreadsheetDemo](https://github.com/mtempel/spreadsheetDemo) to use the [Roo GEM](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) to simplify it and allow for it to cater for local and Google Doc Excel files.(Simply the same just with Roo)
I began by looking at other widgets and sources (similar to this just to a table not graph) that are already using Roo and I have tried to reuse their code for the file source in place of the original, resulting in my code below.
I am trying to use Roo to access the local spreadsheet, take the headings and data for the 6 columns and rows and then push them to a table.
I believe my problem may lie with accessing the speadsheet correctly.
Everything is on the first workbook and starts in cell A1.

Sources I have used:
https://  github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/78#issuecomment-14940695

http://  stackoverflow.com/questions/29400811/use-with-excel-data-to-display-on-dashing-dashboard/29421179?newreg=5c8c7db27d104f5ab3b855c8ea729bc8

```
require 'roo'

#Tried using roo-xls as it started throwing errors saying I needed too.
#require 'roo-xls'


EM.kqueue = EM.kqueue?
file_path = "#{Dir.pwd}/spreadsheet.xls"

def fetch_spreadsheet_data(path)
  s = Roo::Excel.new(path)

    ws = workbook.sheets[0]

  # create an array to hold the lines
    rows = Array.new
    header = Array.new

  # other variables
    up = ws.updated.localtime
    up = up.strftime "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"

    #workbook.default_sheet = workbook.sheets[0]


    # fill lines
    for row in 1..ws.num_rows
      if row == 1
          header.push({ :c1 => ws[row, 1], :c2 => ws[row, 2], :c3 => ws[row, 3], :c4 => ws[row, 4], :c5 => ws[row, 5], :c6 => ws[row, 6]})
      else
        rows.push({ :c1 => ws[row, 1], :c2 => ws[row, 2], :c3 => ws[row, 3], :c4 => ws[row, 4], :c5 => ws[row, 5], :c6 => ws[row, 6]})
      end
    end 
        send_event('spread', :modified => up, :header => header, :rows => rows)
        rescue => err
    #puts "Exception: #{err}"
end



module Handler
  def file_modified
    fetch_spreadsheet_data(path)
  end
end

fetch_spreadsheet_data(file_path)

end
```